# What's the logic behind hilghlighting "sign up" on home page as opposed to "sign in"?

Tags: sign-in

For instance, I wasn't logged in to Github on my phone. So, I go to their website to find that there is no sign in button as opposed to a sign up one.

[image]

(Notice that sign up is all over the place. There is a form, too, below.)

From there, I had two possibilities. Either I press the hamburger menu button and there I can find the two buttons, sign in and sign up, with sign up being outlined.

[image]

Or, I press the sign up button, and I am redirected to a page with indeed, a form to sign up but also a sign in link at the top right.

[image]

That's **two actions** (or even **three** when accessing the sign up page first) to log in.

Why do I have to press the sign up button to then sign in in the first place?

This is the phone screen, though. On a larger screen, we do have direct access to both sign in and sign up.

[image]

But still, why make it so hard for people to log in? I get the call to action but existing users shouldn't be left aside. The other reason I guess would be that they don't expect existing users to log out at all. But when I do have to, I don't want to have to look for the sign in button.

That's one of many examples, though. I just used this one just to get my point across.

Answer (score 1):

Well their main goal then is to get new users instead of signing in the existing ones - at least in the context of this page.
I think it goes with the fact that you can log in "forever" and mostly use the page from a known set of machines so nobody actually uses the Sign in option often, so they direct the page towards the first-time users or the users who haven't signed up yet but are just browsing and the others, who already are members, just use their cookies to get in without clicking anywhere or get redirected to the login page if they are trying to access some dashboard or specific page, but have been logged out.